# Community consensus regarding using backticks or 4 spaces for code

Tags: discussion, editing, community, code-formatting

There might be similar posts regarding this in the past. So, please forgive me.

I often find it hard to edit a post which has lengthy code (indented using 4 spaces). Also, there are higher chances of editing wrong while dealing with lengthy code which is indented using 4 spaces.

So I generally feel indentation is only good for one-line code and backticks are good for multi-line code.

What's the community's opinion about this?

Answer (score 10):

My personal preference is to use the triple backtick as that's the most common way to set code blocks in Markdown outside of Stack Exchange. I find it much easier to use.

When I am editing someone else's post though, if it's a small piece of code, I just select it and click on the `{}` button in the editor. The default behaviour of that button is to use 4 spaces.

If it's a large block of text that needs to be formatted as code, I find it much easier to just add triple backticks at the start and triple backticks at the end.

On a side note, fenced markdown for code blocks wasn't available on SE until it was [released in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/172297).
Another thing to note is that in the case of a very large text, especially logs, using 4 spaces might not be possible as it can cause the post to reach its character limit. Although, I have never encountered this issue myself.

In summary, I don't think we need a consensus. Just go with whatever you prefer until SE decides to stop supporting one of the methods.

Comment: I agree with this but a small correction, the editor button is contextual, if you use it inline it will use back ticks and on a separate line it will use four spaces, it does not change your answer but is worth noting.

Comment: The `Ctrl`+`K` shortcut can also be used instead of the `{}` button (it's also contextual).

Answer (score 4):

Just like [Dan](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19419/250300), I don’t think we need a consensus. In **your** posts, use whatever you want (but keep the difference of in-line vs. block code formatting as [Mark Kirby noted](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19418/250300)).

However, if I edit **someone else’s post**, I apply a bit stricter rules. I use ```` ``` ```` for multi-line code as only the line before and after the code block gets modified in the diff view while with 4 spaces, it would be every line of the block. In the case of a single line code block (mostly a command), I prefer 4 spaces because just one line gets modified – and I save at least 4 bytes<sup>1</sup> of the disk space. ;-)

---

<sup>1</sup> Just double ```` ``` ```` means 6 characters. And each newline means 1–2 characters depending on the platform.

Answer (score 3):

I actually know of five ways to format code on SE, not including the editor button (click edit to see):

`back ticks`

`html`

```
four spaces
```

```
blocks using back ticks
```

```
blocks using tilde
```

I know, that is even more confusing, but if we look at the way they format code, I think we can see that back tick and html are for inline code `like this` and the other are for formatting whole blocks of code.

To back up my claim, if we use the button in the editor, it makes back ticks for `this` and four spaces for

```
this
```

so would strongly imply this is what the different ways to format code were intended for, even if I can't find a direct quote to back it up right now.

Comment: Since I'm a user with low reputation, I can't click edit on meta posts. I suggest you to share the source link.

Comment: Why? You have 800 rep, that should allow suggesting edit surely. It is a long time since I was new but we have a suggested edit queue. Do you see the edit button?

Comment: @MarkKirby There's nothing like edit suggestions for posts on meta.

Comment: There is a whole review queue https://meta.askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits it works just like main but you need five rep to do anything here.

Comment: This is what I'll be shown when I click edit: **Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.**

Comment: @MarkKirby IIRC that's for tag wiki and excerpts only.

Comment: @technastic_tc Well, seems you guys are right, who knew? This seems bizarre to me, I cant see why it would be like this?

Comment: above comment also @Kulfy

Comment: @MarkKirby Do read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87890 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681 IMO, suggested edits should be allowed in meta sites as well. Some relevant feature-requests posted on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129033 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223885

Comment: @technastic_tc I have seen it, I am writing another proposal to allow this on MSE.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it makes any difference at all. I am very used to the 4-spaces indentation, my muscle memory works that way and there is a [nifty userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/3247) that means I can indent by just selecting text and hitting tab, just like you do in many code editors. Selecting a block of text and hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> to indent it, is so common that I am sure many of us will be very tied to it from the various editors we use. I really, really don't want to lose this.

In any case, as far as I can tell, both three backticks and four spaces produce the exact same html rendering, so I really don't see any reason to have guidelines. We can all use whichever of the two (or `~~~`) we prefer.

Comment: It seems that the link to the script does no longer work.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog please comment on the stackapps post then, I can't do anything about that and I want to link to he stackapps post here.

Comment: There are already comments about that on the Stack Apps post. It is possible, after reading the comments, that the OP is not willing to add it back.